# Can I remove these 2 commits in GIT?

Tags: git, commit

Having the structure shown in the picture, Can I delete the commits 0ec08281 and 21736a48?
I think that maybe I could do it using rebase but I'm afraid of deleting also the last commits.

[image: history]

Edit:
I forgot to mention that the commits were pushed to the remote server. However now I'm the only one with access to that server (at least up to now) so there is no chance of messing the source code to other people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an interactive rebase (using the -i) argument, and delete the hashes of the commits that you wish to remove.

*Providing you have **not** pushed your changes to a **shared** repository yet.  Find more information here:*
*http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History*

e.g. `git rebase -i 22782e08`

That should be fine, remember any commit id that is deleted in the interactive script window will be removed, if you wish to abort, delete ALL the commits from the script. There will be on screen instructions regarding this.

Out of interest, why are you deleting them? The graph looks fine to me, if you're doing it for tidiness reasons.

Comment: While changing history is generally safe, it's not a good idea for branches that have been pushed to other repositories. As we don't know whether or not that has happened here, this advice is unsafe.

Comment: It isn't unsafe, it is advice that answers an ambiguous question. I'll update with a warning. Not sure this is worth a downvote.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. I just want to delete them for aesthetic reasons. I did those  commits with a wrong comment and when I tried to amend them GIT created those strange things. So I want to remove them.

Comment: Well if you haven't shared your history with a shared repository, this approach will be fine. If you use revert, this will introduce another commit.

Answer (score 2):

Interactive rebase is not a good idea if you have pushed the changes, you'll be rewriting history.

A better way is to `revert` the changes you don't want

```
git revert 22782e08
```

etc

This will create a **new commit** that undoes the changes in the commit you are reverting.

This is better, because it doesn't change history, but undoes the changes.